# Applied Maths: Equations of Motion

Tags: physics, applications

"A particle of mass m moves in a straight line, so that at time t the particle has a displacement x measured from an origin O. The force acting on the particle is Fsin(ωt), where t is time, and F and ω>0 are constants.

(i) Write down the equation of motion for the particle.

Solution:
mx ̈ = sin(ωt)"

My answer was mx ̈ = Fsin(ωt) but I don't see why the constant F disappears.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math
at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editikng how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps it's due Newton's 2nd law $F=ma$.

Comment: according to Newton's second law Force=mx ̈ and in this question Force=Fsin(ωt) therefore wouldn't mx ̈=Fsin(ωt)?

Comment: You are correct. The equation of motion is $ma = F\sin(\omega t).$

Comment: One way to see that their answer is unsound is to look at units: $m\ddot{x}$ has units of kg*m/s^2 ie Newtons, but $\sin \omega t$ is dimensionless. So you need $F$ in there.

Comment: Ah thank you, that actually helps a lot.